# Как легко проверить метод на наличие аннотации?

Tags: java

У меня есть объект `method` класса `Method` и аннотация `MyAnnotation`. К сожалению, не нашел в объекте `method` метод вроде `hasAnnotation`.

Возникает вопрос: **есть ли уже какие-то стандартные способы узнать аннотирован ли метод?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Через стандартный метод isAnnotationPresent():

```
 Method method = ...
 if (method.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
     ...
 }
```

В случае, ели кроме наличия аннотации нужно проверить еще и ее параметры, есть метод getAnnotation():

```
 MyAnnotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
 if (annotation != null) {
     System.out.println(annotation.value);
 }
```